# Update details after retrieving the list item by index

Tags: c#

I am unable to update the details after retrieving the list item by index(How should I update the details after retrieving a list item?)

```cs
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Updating the student details");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the index at which to update a student details");
    
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < Student.Count; i++)
    {
        if(i==index)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id:{0} \nName:{1} \nMarks:{2}", Student[i].Name, Student[i].ID, Student[i].Marks);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("What details you want to update?");
    }
}                   
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
break;
```

Expected Output-->The code should except user input in Int form and fetch the details(by using the index) and return the fetched details to user, then user should be able to modify the details and the modified details should be updated to the list of student details.The Student list contains(string Name,int ID,int Marks).

Comment: What about just using `Console.WriteLine("Id:{0} \nName:{1} \nMarks:{2}", Student[index].Name, Student[index].ID, Student[index].Marks);` instead of your whole `for` loop?

Comment: You'd have to ensure `index` is less than or equal to the bounds of the list to avoid errors though.

Comment: yes Ibrennan208, that does the work, but now I have to modify/update a particular student details and after editing I have to replace the orginal deatils with the updated/modified details and store it in the same list. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Something like: `Student[index].Name = Console.ReadLine();`, or `Student[index].Name = "New Name";`

Comment: Thanks ibrennan208, now after modifying the list the old student details is not replaced by the new student details, it is added beside the old student details. Please Help

Answer (score 3):

You can use a menu with a key to update individual property of the student.

Here is the student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student(int id, string name, int marks)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Marks = marks;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {ID} \nName:{Name} \nMarks:{Marks}";
    }
}
```

I have overridden ToString() to format print the student detail.

Insertion of dummy data into studentList,

```
Random generator = new Random();
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    studentList.Add(
        new Student(i, $"Student {i}", generator.Next(60, 101))
    );
}
```

Implementation of updating part with index out of bound check,

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the index at which to update a student details");
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (index >= studentList.Count)
        throw new Exception("Out of bound student index");

    Console.WriteLine(studentList[index]);

    Console.WriteLine("What details you want to update?");

    Console.WriteLine("1. ID\n2. Name\n3.Marks");

    int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter new ID: ");
            int newId = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            studentList[index].ID = newId;
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter new Name: ");
            string newName = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
            studentList[index].Name = newName;
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter new Marks: ");
            int newMarks = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            studentList[index].Marks = newMarks;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice");
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(studentList[index]);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Hello Methran GS thanks a lot, but my code is kinda different the switch statement that you have in your code is a SUB SWITCH for my code, I want to know where I am wrong, so how can I share my code So that you could check it up and guide me.

Comment: Use pastebin to share your code